# How to link static library .a generated from linux to a windows c project

Tags: linux, windows, static-libraries

I have a static library `mylib.a` generated under Linux. Now how can I link it to a project under windows environment? The `mylib.a` provides functions for others to call. The reason I build this library in Linux is because everything has already been set up in Linux.

Comment: What is that `mylib.a`, how did you get it, what is it supposed to do? If you gave more details we could help you more concretely. Sounds like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Explain what is your actual goal (so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52490846/edit) your question to add more motivation and context) and what is your project. BTW, even for Linux`mylib.a` is not enough alone. You need its header files and documentation!

Comment: Without additional details, your question is unclear. Because you just cannot.

Comment: Please do not cross post: https://superuser.com/questions/1361051/how-do-i-make-windows-run-linux-executables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have a static library mylib.a generated under Linux. Now how can I link it to a project under windows environment?

You simply **cannot** do that (unless on Windows you'll use some Linux compatibility layer like [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)). Because Windows and Linux are very different and incompatible : different [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (for Linux, listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html); on Windows, the set of system calls is not well documented), different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (for Linux, see [this](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)), different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), different [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) format (for Linux, [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format); for Windows, [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)), different library format and different [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) concepts (so the notion of [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) is different and incompatible on Windows and on Linux).

BTW, a static library is not enough alone (even on Linux only) so is useless by itself. You need additional [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) files and documentation to use it in a project.

You could read something like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand better what an OS is and provides. An entire book is needed. Then you could dive into the specific OS API for your system (e.g. for Linux, read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or something newer -related to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)- and the [`man` pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/); for Windows, study in details the [WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433218%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

My recommendation is to always **deal with source code** (above what your OS provides). So if you can get the source code of `mylib.a` you might [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) it to Windows (and that could take years of work, if that library is Linux or POSIX  specific).

Be aware that several frameworks exist to provide a nearly common [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) (at source code level) on Linux and Windows and MacOSX. For example, [Qt](http://qt.io/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), and *many* others. If you code in C or C++ for one of these frameworks (and nothing else!), porting your source code from Windows to Linux or vice versa should be really easy. However, some difference still remains: file paths, font names, command language (and many other resources) etc... are still different on Linux and on Windows.